# 2D array is not adhering to row and col dimensions correctly - Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am creating a small java program for class that takes in a list of ints and doubles from a file and builds them into a 2D array, then sorts the array. The file would be something like,

```
4
5
3.00
5.67
4.56
etc
```

The first two ints are taken as the row and column sizes for the array, and the rest of the doubles are filled into the array. But I am having a problem getting my program to create the arrays when the row and col dimensions are two different numbers, as in 5x4 rather than 4X4. I realize I must be missing something, but I am not sure what. 
Here is my method that reads the file and builds it into the array:

```
    public static double[][] readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName + ".txt"));
    int row = reader.nextInt();
    int col = reader.nextInt();
    double[][] array = new double[row][col];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
            array[i][j] = reader.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    return array;

}
```

Any tips would be appreciated. Note that I *have* made sure that there are the sufficient double amounts in the file to be read into a 5x4 etc. array. Also this only errors when the row is bigger than the col (so 4x5 works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
        array[i][j] = reader.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious mistake is in the inner loop, use `array[i].length` rather than `array.length`

```
for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
    array[i][j] = reader.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 But I am having a problem getting my program to create the arrays when the row
 and col dimensions are two different numbers, as in 5x4 rather than 4X4.
```

You need to make a subtle change in your loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
```

Change to

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array[row].length; j++){  // notice subtle change
```

`rows` = array.length, (lenghth is how many rows);.

`colulmns` = how lon the row is (array[row].length.